# How to switch between old JDK version to new JDK version and how to set system variable value in this situation?

Tags: java, cassandra, path, environment-variables, system-variable

Recently I have installed Cassandra on my windows 10 laptop. In Cassandra specification, they mentioned that this version is suitable with only Java 8 and Python 2 Versions. But on my laptop, I'm already having java 16 and python 3 versions. After Cassandra download is completed IN SYSTEM VARIABLES Variable Name "Java Home" variable value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2 is replaced with C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\  and how to set system variable value in this situation. Because I have to use both Cassandra and Java 16 for certain tasks.

Comment: Just run Cassandra in docker?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but I wanted to let you know that there is very limited Windows support in Cassandra 3.11 and there are several known issues that will not be fixed due to limitations in the operating system.

Furthermore, Windows support has been completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 due to lack of maintainers and testing ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

As a workaround, we recommend the following:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-docker-image)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

If you just want to build apps with Cassandra as a backend, [Astra DB](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) has a free tier that lets you launch a Cassandra cluster in a few clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!